# What's the difference between computation and symbolic manipulation?

Tags: definitions

I have lived my academic career thinking these two terms were interchangeable but something arose in me that said they're distinct. Are there any logical, formal definitions distinguishing between the two?

Comment: I would not classify numeric computation as symbolic manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak for me (and maybe my interpretation is also caused by a different understanding of the English language), but I would say

1. Computation: That's numerical. Solving a problem by calculation with numbers.
2. Symbolic manipulation: That's like analysis. Solving the problem by e.g. term transformation, if I say, I get the solution b, by transforming a + b = c to b = c - a.